# Asterisk test ISDN card

Tags: asterisk

I have an AVM ISDN controller C4 plugged into an asterisk machine.

It shows up in the PCI device list as:

`Digital Equipment Corporation StrongARM DC21285 (rev 04)`

How can I test this card to see its working from Asterisk, if possible without plugging actual phones into it?

Anybody knows a command for it inside Asterisk's CLI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dahdi-tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/dahdi_tool.8.html) for this.